# prepositions with break

Tags: prepositions

I looked up Google Ngram and found that we can use any one of *at*, *in*, *on* before *break*, but we can only say *at lunch break* and *on lunch break*.

Is what I've got right and do they have any difference when used with different preposition?

Comment: Not necessarily *only* one preposition. Trying to make someone go through a doorway immediately, for example, you could say ***Go on it at once!***

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong. You cannot say 'in lunch break'.

So both can be *at*, *on*. Neither can be *in*.

"In the lunch room", "in the break room" are acceptable.

Comment: It might well be fairly non-idiomatic to say ***in lunch break*** in most contexts, but that's primarily because we'd normally expect an article or other determiner regardless of which specific preposition is used. *I read the paper **in** my lunch break* sounds fine to me, as does the same with ***on***, but personally I don't much like ***at*** in that context.

Comment: As an American, that sounds wrong to me. "in my lunch break" would make me say, "you mean _in the lunch room_?". "At lunch" is about as common a phrase as you can hear over here. "at lunch break" is awkward, but doesnt sound wrong.

Comment: I think you are wrong to say the OP was wrong. The question seems to say we can say any of the following: "in break" "on break" or "at break", but we can only say "at lunch break" and "on lunch break". So, the OP's assumptions agree with your assertions.

Comment: I'm surprised, but comparing relative prevalence of [the AmE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+lunch+break&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20lunch%20break%3B%2Cc0) and [the BrE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+lunch+break&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20lunch%20break%3B%2Cc0) for ***in the lunch break*** suggests that particular prepositional use is about 4 times more common on my side of the pond. A little-known usage split!

Comment: @J.R. I said "in break" was incorrect. That is why I said the OP was wrong. However after reading FF's comments, I think these may all be more dialect based than I realized.

Comment: [AmE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+lunch+break%2Cat+the+lunch+break&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20lunch%20break%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20lunch%20break%3B%2Cc0) has ***at** the lunch break* twice as common as ***in***. But [BrE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+lunch+break%2Cat+the+lunch+break&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20lunch%20break%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20lunch%20break%3B%2Cc0) is precisely ***opposite**!*

Comment: Jamie - just goes to show that even though we think that as native speakers (which I assume you are too) we're the ones who actually *know* all about the things asked here on ELL, sometimes we discover stuff we never even suspected!

Comment: (I just made a "non-edit" to your answer text so I could retract my downvote, which in retrospect seems a somewhat hasty judgement! :)

Comment: That is elaborate discussion here, but after reading all your comments, are you saying I can also say in the break lunch. Thus I can use them without any restriction. Did I get it right? Sorry, I become more confused.

Comment: @Young It depends on dialect. In the US, you cannot say "in the lunch break". In the UK, you can.

Comment: Thank you so much. but could you tell me which one is the most idiomatic in terms of lunch break and lunch. To the best of my knowledge, I would say at lunch and on the lunch break. Am I right?

Comment: @Young In the US, "(They are) at lunch" and "(They are) on lunch break". "At lunch" is probably the most common.

Comment: @JamieClinton - Except your answer doesn't say "in break" is incorrect. It says, "in lunch break" is incorrect. When I read the question, it looked like the OP was wondering (rather astutely, I think), if "in break" might be acceptable in some contexts, but not with "lunch break." It's a fair question; after all, if a courtroom can be "in recess", than could it not also be "in break"?

Comment: @ J.R.♦ Thanks for your supplement. I came up with another question regarding your answer. I'm not sure whether I need to post another thread for this. I guess the last sentence in your reply mean if we have a precedent in recess, so we can use in break as well, but I've never seen 'than could it not also be'. Could you please explain its usage?